Cloth-simulation acts weird with body or armature
im new at blender and decided to try out the cloth modifier and got into some issue with rigging
after frame to frame it starts getting "swallowed by body" 
I attached cape to the back bone, did some pin group, have collision applied at cape and at the body and really cant find what could be the issue. Appreciate any help!

Check out this video and see if any of these changes help. I found it pretty helpful myself.
